# Using Angular.js and Restangular, how can I hook into when all child requests inside a loop are complete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

Using Angular.js and Restangular, how can I hook into when all child requests inside a loop are complete? For example:

```
Restangular.all('clusters').getList().then(function(clusters) {
     clusters.forEach(function(cluster, index) {
         cluster.get().then(function(response) {
             //some logic
         });
     });
});
```

Essentially I need to know when **all** child requests to `cluster.get()` are complete and then do something. Is there a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) method to await all of the requests. It would work something like this:

```
Restangular.all('clusters').getList().then(function(clusters) {
    var promises = clusters.map(function(cluster, index) {
        return cluster.get().then(function(response) {
            //some logic
        });
    });

    return $q.all(promises);
}).then(function() {
    // logic for when all of the get methods are complete
});
```